# Retrieve email server information form an email address

Tags: node.js, email, dns

Given an email address, like "user@example.com", I'm trying to ascertain information about the email server they use, information like:

- Domain
- Port
- Uses TLS

Currently, I can split the email address into two parts (for instance user and example.com), then do a MX lookup on the domain in order to attempt to ascertain the mail domain used:

```
dns.resolveMx(hostname, callback)
```

However, several hosts seem to use other servers than those (for instance, JustHost encourages all their domains from example.com to justXX.justhost.com in order to provide them with TLS) and attaining those is proving to be tricky.

The port is okay, as long as they use a default port, else as far as I can see it's impossible and TLS is easy to work out as long as I have both the domain and the port in order to contact the server.

Since all these methods seem unreliable at the best of times, are there better methods of ascertaining this information?  This is in relation to making a mail client, which attempts to logon to the mail server to retrieve emails, and using the SMTP protocol in order to send emails from that server.

Answer (score 0):

The only information that you can rely on is what is available in DNS. This is all of the info that is needed to send mail for a given address.

If you want to receive emails then it's an entirely different story. You didn't mention which mail server you need. The server that gets the incoming email? The server that lets user send email? The server that lets users download their emails? I'm assuming that you want the server that you can send email for that domain to - what is available as MX in DNS.

You didn't mention why you need that info but if you want it so you could send emails for those domains then you can sonsider using a transactional email service like or Mailgun, Mandrill or Amazon SES because it will handle all of those details for you. But you didn't say what is the purpose of getting that info so I don't know if that will help you, I'm adding it just in case.

Comment: Apologies, my question was indeed ambiguous.  I'll edit it now, but the tl;dr is that I'm attempting to make a mail client and trying to automatically retrieve domain/port information from the email address entered.  From what I've read online I don't think this question has a good answer and I do have to force users to enter in their own information unless it's from a hard-coded list of popular email providers.